# Use concatenated string as previous definded variable

Tags: python, string, variables, type-conversion

I have several measaring points (x,y,z coordinate), each as a list und want to create a list consisting of all measaring point lists.
My problem is that when i loop over all lists I create each name as a string and it gets entered as a string and not as the actual variable in the complete list.

Here's my code:

```
listCoos = []

coo1 = [754, -125, 947]
coo2 = [345, -35, -157]
coo3 = [-64, -1345, 57]

number = 1
for i in range(3):
    position = "coo" + str(number)
    listCoos.append(koo)
    number += 1
print(listCoos)
```

This is my Output:

```
['kooTuer1', 'kooTuer2', 'kooTuer3']
```

I am expecting this Output:

```
[[754, -125, 947],[345, -35, -157],[-64, -1345, 57]]
```

This is probably a fairly stupid mistake I am making, but I am a beginner in coding overall.

Thanks for your help!

Gunnar

Comment: That's not at all what your code outputs. Your code raises a NameError.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be a solution to use a dict with the lists names as keys. So you can iterate over them with dict.items()

Comment: Thank You, but will it not be the same problem if I assign each key (coo1,2,3) the values(x,y,z)? While writing this, your idea might seem to work, because it will either give me an error or do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
listCoos.append(coo1)
listCoos.append(coo2)
listCoos.append(coo3)
```

Comment: I know, that this will work, thank you. It will be problematik and space consuming and ugly looking, if I have 50+ Coo-Sets.

Comment: Well just then do: for i in range(i): listCoos.append([x,y,z]) and change the parameters for which are you interested, you can have a .json or a txt and change the values from x,y,z from that txt

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Your `position` is just a string indeed. That is not how python treats variables. Accessing variables with a string by their names is either a bed practice or very intentional meta-programming which you should be very careful with. I'd suggest adding variables directly to the list:

```
listCoos = [coo1, coo2, coo3]
```

If you have many variables, you probably need to reconsider the way you generate them, i.e. maybe you can add values directly to a list without creating a standalone variable.

---

***DON'T DO THE FOLLOWING***

I will just leave it here:

```
listCoos = []

coo1 = [754, -125, 947]
coo2 = [345, -35, -157]
coo3 = [-64, -1345, 57]

for i in range(1, 4):
    position = "coo" + str(i)
    listCoos.append(globals()[position])

print(listCoos)
```

This will do what you were trying to do. But as I mentioned that is not the way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, Yevhen. I think I have to reconsider my approach, since the number of Coordinate Sets will be decided be my. I just wanted to make an overall list in a somewhat elegant way..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    listCoos = []

    coo1 = [754, -125, 947]
    coo2 = [345, -35, -157]
    coo3 = [-64, -1345, 57]

    for i in range(1,4):
        listCoos.append(eval('coo'+str(i)))
    print(listCoos)

    [[754, -125, 947], [345, -35, -157], [-64, -1345, 57]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the "eval" was the command I was missing!

Comment: , you could also try using dictionaries to make it more pythonic